# NoMethodError on comment.user.name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

EDIT: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

I have my comments up and ready, but when I to display the comments user name I get a NoMethodError. When I replace comment.user.name with comment.user_id, I get a result, so what's going on here?

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <div class="media">
        <div class"media-body"
            <h4 class="media-heading">
            <ul>
                <li><%= comment.body %> :by <%= comment.user.name> </li>
            </ul>
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Here are the Post and Comment
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :topic

```
default_scope { order('created_at DESC') }

    validates :title, length: {minimum: 5}, presence: true
    validates :body, length: {minimum: 20}, presence: true
    validates :topic, presence: true
    validates :user, presence: true
```

end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end

---

In a migration when I added users to comments in my most recent I added a user_id column thinking I could link id_s to names, but I look at how the [ROR guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/getting_started.html) is associating users and comments.

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :commenter
      t.text :body
      t.references :post

      t.timestamps
  end

     add_index :comments, :post_id
  end
end
```

It's something like this, but I don't want anyone without a user_id commenting, so I have to get the user_id to pull up a name somehow.

---

Here are the models for user and comment

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  has_many :posts
  has_many :comment
    mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

 class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :post
   belongs_to :user
 end
```

Comment: What is the relationship between your models. Please add them in the question.

Comment: Can you post the error. A NoMethodError would indicate that the `name` method does not exist on the user model. Particularly if `user_id` is working.

Comment: added my models to an edit above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

This means that no instance of `User` model has been assigned a `comment`, so:

1. Verify that a `User` has been assigned to `Comment`
2. Make sure that you have create `user_id` field for `comment` table, and declared  `belongs_to :user` in the `Comment` model.
3. Don't forget to migrate the new schema, if you aren't sure, just rerun it.
4. When you've migrated validate the **spec/dummy/db/schema.rb** that the proper column has been added.
5. Make sure that there are no `attr_accessor/reader :name`, or you haven't explicitly defined the `#name` method for the `Comment` model.
6. If you are using the state machine, make sure that you have no `:name` event.
7. In some cases `Rails` doesn't reload models, and (as far as I know) it never reloads the DB, forcely reload the `Rails` to make sure that model, and schemas are picked up, i.e. kill the server, and restart it again.
8. To know where is the instance method `#name` of class `Comment` is defined, issue:

   ```
   Comment.instance_method(:name).source_location
   # => [".../gems/activerecord-~.~.~/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb", ~~]
   ```

   The valid file is like the same: **association.rb**
9. One yet reason, is for example in seeding, when you assigning a user to a comment, you assign just `user_id`, but in case a User with such `#id` does't exist, access to comment with be as follows:

   ```
   comment.user_id # => 5
   comment.user # => nil
   ```

   So you have to fix the situation when you are assigning `#id`s and not `User` records themselves.

Comment: If I already have `has_many :comment` in your User Model, and `belongs_to :user` in your Comment Model, what else could be the issue?

Comment: These are in my comments table so far before updating my schema, so I think it's there already, unless the schema update is providing something else.

`add_index "comments", ["post_id"], name: "index_comments_on_post_id"

  add_index "comments", ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id"`

Comment: are you available to chat?

Comment: @ClydeBrown now yes =)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66841/discussion-between-clyde-brown-and--).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the association between the models. Looks like you missed it if I am not wrong. You have the user_id column in the comments table but the association should also be set up in the models

**Comment Model**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Also if you want to get the comments from user model add the below code.

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comment
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: it should be `has_many :comment`. Just add the the two association in both the models and see if it works. It mostly will. :-)

Comment: There is another chance that there is no user record for the comment you are trying. So the `comment.user` is returning `nil`. Hence when you try `comment.user.name` it throws error. Check if there is an user for the comment. If not then create a new user and associate the user to the comment by putting the value of `user.id` into `comment.user_id`

Comment: yea, when I replace the user.name with user_id, that shows up. so maybe there isn't a name associated with an id. How would I add one?

Comment: `comment.user_id = User.first` and then `comment.save`. Also I think you are new to rails. I would recommend you go through [Lynda's Rails Essential training](http://www.lynda.com/Ruby-Rails-tutorials/Ruby-Rails-3-Essential-Training/55960-2.html). Its not free but certainly helpful.